# How to trigger animate.css on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, animate.css

I am using Dan Eden's animate.css to animate my slideshow elements. This is how I trigger animations on page load:

**CSS:**

```
body.loading .animated {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s !important;
  animation-duration: 60s !important;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 60s !important;
  animation-delay: 60s !important;
}
```

First I delay all animations 60s. Which should be enough to load any site.
Than I remove `.loading` from body on page load, so that the default *.animated* delay and duration of 1s is being used.

**JS**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery("body").removeClass("loading");
});
```

This was working like a charm until I updated Google Chrome a couple of days ago. It is still working fine in all other browsers. Just Chrome is giving me a headache here. Looks like the 60s delay is still being used, though the class of `.loading` has been removed from body.

I would like to know if anyone has a working solution to trigger animate.css on page load.

Comment: could u plz provide the http://jsfiddle.net/ for it..

Comment: Why don't you use window.load to add the `animated` class itself. Then you can take the guesswork out of waiting for it to load.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is for a client, who will add animations by himself and doesn't know a thing about Javascript. So all he is able to do is to add a class of animated to an element.